# Restart passenger synchronously?

Tags: passenger

Is there a way to restart a passenger server synchronously?
Running `touch tmp/restart.txt` will restart the server, but the touch command is asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow up the `touch tmp/restart.txt` command with `curl -I http://your-server`. That will cause passenger to immediately restart your application.

Is that the functionality you were after?

Comment: Yeah, that will work. But I think I was looking for something like [zero downtime deployment](http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment).

Comment: Passenger offers zero downtime functionality in their enterprise edition through "rolling restarts". E.g. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRollingRestarts